# Given a group $G$ of order $102=(2 \cdot 3 \cdot 17) $ and $|Z(G)|=2$, show that $G/Z(G)$ has a subgroup of order 17.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I can't find the answer to this question.
Given a group $G$ of order $102=(2 \cdot 3 \cdot 17) $ and $|Z(G)|=2$, show that $G/Z(G)$ has a subgroup of order 17.

These were my thoughts: The order of $G/Z(G)$ is of course $3 \cdot 17$. So the only possible (non-trivial) subgroups are of order $3$ or $17$ since $G/Z(G)$ is not cyclic. 
I think a normal subgroup of order $3$ could be useful, but I'm not sure...

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's theorem? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29

Comment: @Landscape while that is true, I don't think you can prove that without first proving that it has a subgroup of order $17$ anyway.

Comment: Sure it makes sense. We assume something false and are asked to prove something. This is fine (though maybe not a great idea from a pedagogical perspective).

Comment: @Landscape (I thought that was what it said actually). Sure, no group with these properties can exist. That does not prevent us from proving that if it existed it would have certain properties.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some hints on how to do this without Cauchy: The setup is not really needed, we just need that the group has order $3\cdot 17$, since we would clearly have a subgroup as the desired one if it was cyclic.

So we can assume that all non-identity elements have order $3$. Now, if it has a normal subgroup $N$ of order $3$, and $H$ is another subgroup of order $3$, what can you say about the order of $HN$? Get a contradiction from this.

So now consider a subgroup $H$ of order $3$ and the normalizer $N_G(H)$. Show that we must have $N_G(H) = H$ and that this means that there are 17 conjugates of $H$ in $G$. Now count how many elements of order $3$ these give you in total and see that adding the identity will leave you with too few elements.

So consider one more subgroup of order $3$ and do the same again, counting elements. Show that this will not work out to the correct number of total elements (you get too may this time).

Answer (score 1):

According to the first Sylow theorem, if $p$ is a prime factor of $|G|$, then $G$ has an element of order $p$ (and therefore a cyclic subgroup of that order).

Comment: Apologies to Dune, Cauchy did prove a sufficient version of that theorem.

Comment: This seems a strange exercise if the asker is allowed to use Cauchy or Sylow (as it becomes trivial).

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry... I'm only following an introductory course on group theory so I didn't know Cauchy's theorem...

Comment: No, that's my bad. You're probably getting to the point where your prof. would introduce the Sylow theorems, so actually utilizing the theorem itself is premature.